# Pytube progress only shows 99 and 100

Tags: python, youtube, pytube

I am trying to show progress in pytube while its downloading a video. but it only shows 99 and 100, and then Completed.

Here is my code:

```
from pytube import YouTube
import os

max_file_size = 0

def on_progress(stream, data_chunk, bytes_remaining):
    percent = int(100 - (100 * (bytes_remaining/max_file_size)))
    print(percent)

def on_comp(stream, path):
    print('Completed')

yt = YouTube('https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxYbHzn8bbU&t=84s', 
    on_progress_callback=on_progress, on_complete_callback=on_comp)       
video = yt.streams.first()
max_file_size = video.filesize
video.download(os.getcwd())
```

Output:

```
99
100
Completed
```

Thanks!

Comment: maybe video is too short and it download all in one chunk. Did you check how big file you get?

Comment: The file size is 9MB.

Comment: it is very small file. Try something much longer.

Comment: or you should select different format because your code always download in `.3gpp` and it is always very small file.

Comment: try `video = yt.streams[2]` or `video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()` instead of `video = yt.streams.first()` and it will download `.mp4` which has `45MB` and it displays `20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%`

Comment: Ok @furas. I will try your suggestion and let you know.

Comment: digging in source code I found in [pytube.request](https://pytube.io/en/latest/_modules/pytube/request.html) like `default_range_size = 9437184  # 9MB` which is used as chunk size - so it loads `9MB` in one chunk. If you could change it into smaller value then it will display percent for smaller files.

Comment: Thank you alot @furas. It works now. Now I know that my function is working properly, its just the chunk size.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Digging in source code I found in [pytube.request](https://pytube.io/en/latest/_modules/pytube/request.html) line

```
default_range_size = 9437184  # 9MB
```

which is used as chunk size in lines

```
stop_pos = min(downloaded + default_range_size, file_size) - 1
range_header = f"bytes={downloaded}-{stop_pos}"
```

so it download `9MB` in one chunk.

You download file which has only `~9MB` so it downloads almost all in one chunk and it can display only `99%` or `100%`.

If you try with longer file using

```
video = yt.streams[2] 
# or 
video = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
# or
video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()
```

then it will download `~45MB` and it will display `20%, 40%, 60%, 80%, 100%`

---

Maybe if you could change `default_range_size` into smaller value then it will display percent for smaller files too - but I think it would need to change it directly in source code, so you can't do it in easy way.

---

Minimal working code - with other small changes.

I use

- `f'{percent:.0%}'` to display `0.20` as `20%` so I don't have to calculate it as on my own,
- `f'{max_file_size:_}'` to display size as `104_465_890` instead of `104465890`,
- `end='\r'` to display percent in in the same line and replace previous value.

```
from pytube import YouTube

def on_progress(stream, data_chunk, bytes_remaining):
    #print('bytes_remaining:', bytes_remaining)
    downloaded = max_file_size - bytes_remaining
    percent = downloaded/max_file_size
    print(f'Downloaded: {percent:.0%}', end='\r')

def on_complete(stream, path):
    print('Completed:', path)

# --- main ---

url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aqz-KE-bpKQ'  # "Big Buck Bunny" ~100MB
#url = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxYbHzn8bbU' # ~45MB

yt = YouTube(url,
             on_progress_callback=on_progress,
             on_complete_callback=on_complete)

#for item in yt.streams:
#    print(item)

#video = yt.streams[2]
#video = yt.streams.get_by_itag(22)
video = yt.streams.get_highest_resolution()

max_file_size = video.filesize
print(f'Size: {max_file_size:_} bytes')

video.download(skip_existing=False)
```